# Write / change raw ID3 tags?

Tags: id3, id3v2, factor-lang

I have an MP3 file:

```
B{
    255 251 144 100 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 73 110 102 111 0 0 0 15
    0 0 30 161 0 50 3 66 0 3 5 8 10 13 15 18 20 24 26 28
    31 33 36 38 41 43 47 49 52 54 56 59 61 64 66 69 72
    75 77 79 82 84 87 89 92 95 98 100 103 105 107 110
    112 115 118 ~3277535 more~
}
```

And I have some metadata I want to put in it:

```
H{
    { "title" "Superstar (feat. Krewella)" }
    { "artist" "Pegboard Nerds & NGHTMRE" }
    { "num" 1 }
}
```

Factor doesn't have a vocabulary to write ID3 tags (yet), but I have the raw file data and some data I'd like to write.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#ID3v2) isn't any help, and the [mpg123](https://www.mpg123.de/api/mpg123_8h_source.shtml#l01162) source doesn't really clear anything up either.

How do I put the data from the hashtable into the ID3v2 header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have support for writing id3 tags yet. But python has and we have support for wrapping Python modules. So if you are willing to be pragmatic first `sudo pip install mutagen` then:

```
USING: kernel python python.syntax sequences ;
IN: examples.python.mutagen

PY-QUALIFIED-FROM: mutagen.easyid3 => EasyID3 ( name -- obj ) ;
PY-METHODS: mutagen:easyid3:EasyID3 =>
    __setitem__ ( self key value -- )
    save ( self -- ) ;

: <EasyID3> ( str -- easyid3 )
    >py mutagen.easyid3:EasyID3 ;

: setitem ( obj key val -- )
    [ >py ] bi@ __setitem__ ;

: update-tags ( easyid3 assoc -- )
    dupd [ first2 setitem ] with each save ;
```

Then you can write id3 tags like this:

```
[
    "/path/to/mp3-file.mp3" <EasyID3>  
    { 
        { "title" "Superstar (feat. Krewella)" }
        { "artist" "Pegboard Nerds & NGHTMRE" }
    } update-tags
] with-destructors
```

Of course doing it in pure Factor isn't impossible. But you would have to study up on the mp3 and id3v1-2 specifications.